# Laravel Model Relation Where Many-to-Many Exists

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

Consider the following relational structure (using Laravel Eloquent relationships):

`Assessment --> belongsToMany --> Users`

`Assessment --> hasMany --> Action Item`

`Action Item --> belongsToMany --> Users`

In practice, what this means is that a single Assessment can be assigned to many different users, then once an Action Item is created, that item can be assigned to any or all of those users.

Currently, I have one Eloquent relationship between a Assessments and Action Items - `hasMany`. Simple enough. However, it would be ideal if I could create *two* additional  relationships: `assignedActionItems` and `unassignedActionItems`. In other words, one would return Action Items where their own relationship to users was empty, and the other would return Action Items where it is not.

In short, is a relationship such as this possible?

```
public function assignedActionItems() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Entities\ActionItem')
                ->where( ** ACTIONITEM->USERS IS NOT EMPTY ** );
}

public function unassignedActionItems() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Entities\ActionItem')
                ->where( ** ACTIONITEM->USERS IS EMPTY ** );
}
```

And if it is, how?

I'm already implementing it via an `$appends` attribute, but it would feel cleaner and be capable of lazy-loading, etc. if I could write it as an actual relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like you should be able to check for the existence of a relationship, rather than defining new relationships.

From https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence:

```
// Retrieve all action items that have been assigned to at least one user ...
$actionItems = App\ActionItem::has('assigned')->get();
```

You can also narrow down your query further by adding required counts or additional `where` conditions.